# onclick="$.post(this.href); return false;" not working right

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, onclick

JavaScript/jQuery noob here. I'm trying to POST a `href` but without the page reloading.

Reading around the internet, I see that you *should* be able to add `onclick="$.post(this.href); return false;"` to the href, but it's not working for me and the page is reloading.

Shoehorning this into my PHP code looks like:

`echo "<a href='".$url."post=$post_ID' onclick=\"$.post(this.href); return false;\">".$var['add']."</a>";`

Any tips why the page is refreshing when clicking that href?

Comment: Can you post more of your JS code?

Comment: Perhaps that's part of my problem. That **is** my code. Like I said, I'm a bit of a rookie and haven't found a solid rtfm on this.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Based on this info my best guess is that jQuery not loaded

Comment: Well, I tried the HTML *I* expect your PHP to output, and it works as you want it to. Please post your generated HTML - I think it will reveal the problem.

Comment: *facepalm*. @Tigra can you put your comment into an answer and I'll check it for you? It's been a long day combined with my rookieness, I forgot to load jQuery.

Comment: @Pat I expect your browser's JS console would have told you that `$ is not defined` if you had looked in it...

Comment: `echo`ing html is silly. If you just close your `php` tag, you can directly output html. I find this to be much more readable and you don't have to deal with quotes being escaped. `<a href="<?=$url?>?post=<?=$post_ID?>" onclick="$.post(this.href); return false;"><?=$var['add']?></a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucky guess over here, jquery not loaded :)

> Based on this info my best guess is that jQuery not loaded

Comment: Sometimes we overlook the obvious. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This might help: The below code will bind the `onClick` event of the element with the `id` of `someID` and then send it's `href` attribute to a PHP script called `test.php`. Hope this helps.

**Example HTML:**

```
 <a href="some_href" id="someID">Click me to post</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
 $("#someID").on('click', function(){
        var hrefAttr = this.href;
        $.post("test.php", { href: hrefAttr } );        
    });
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('href')` is (almost) just `this.href` - the main difference is that the latter will always be an absolute URL.

Comment: Looks interesting. I'll give this a whirl as well. Thank you

Comment: @Alnitak Are you suggesting I change the above to `this.href` instead of `$(this).href`?

Comment: @Evan not necessarily, I'm just suggesting that _sometimes_ using jQuery methods to access a node's properties is overkill.

Comment: @Alnitak I agree. In this case the main reason I went with jQuery was for the clean binding of the click event as opposed to inline JS. Thank you for the tips by the way.

Comment: By all means jQuery for the event binding, I'm just fed up of seeing code like `$(this).attr('id')` when `this.id` works perfectly well and is a) shorter, and b) much more efficient.

Comment: @Alnitak Well, I appreciate the comments. I learned something new today.

Comment: oh, also +please+ do use `.on('click', ...)` instead of `.click` ;-)  The jQuery API will be much nicer if they ever get around to deprecating those overloaded functions which either _register_ a handler or _trigger_ a handler depending on the args.